# Modeling Database Relationship Where Certain Rows Cannot be Deleted

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord

Ok, sorry for the weird wording.

I have a situation where I have a set number of database rows that cannot be removed. Let's call them ingredients. I have many ingredients that belong to recipes. However, these recipes use the same ingredients. And by use the same that means that they have to use exactly the same row because these ingredients are seeded by an external script. In other words, these ingredients are never created by the application itself but are preloaded.

This is the problem. I want to be able to delete the recipe without deleting the ingredient but I would like the ingredient to still belong to them.

Advice?

Comment: I don't understand. You have an ingredients table and a recipe table referencing the ingredients. You want to delete recipes without deleting their ingredients. And why should it even happen? You delete from recipes, so it is only recipes you delete and the ingredients table stays untouched. I see no problem.

Comment: " but I would like the ingredient to still belong to them" To them? To whom?

Comment: Because admins should be able to remove recipes for testing, filtering, etc. I still want those ingredients however.

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment (don't have enough rep), so I'm posting this as an answer. I think you can create a table that stores ingredient_id and recipe_id, call it RecipeToIngredients or something like that. You can then relate the ingredient_id to the records in the ingredients table, and the recipe_id to the recipe table. You can have multiple recipes linking to exactly the same ingredient row.

You say you want to delete the recipe without deleting the ingredient, so you can do that with this setup. When you delete the recipe, you can delete the records from the RecipeToIngredients table, and not delete them from the Ingredients table.

Then you say "I would like the ingredient to still belong to them". By "them", do you mean still belong to the Recipe? If so, then I wouldn't delete the Recipe, maybe create an "Active" field on the recipe table and set it to inactive. Or you could still delete the Recipe and keep the records on the RecipeToIngredients table, but then you will have a recipe_id value in that table that doesn't mean anything. If by "them" you don't mean the Recipe, then if you would clarify what you do mean, that would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, this seem the good way: using a join table in the middle with a `ON DELETE CASCADE` constraint

Comment: I like this - I will try this. Thank you.

Comment: Great - let me know how it goes.